# Why I am getting zero values for Facebook page status read?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am facing problem in getting Facebook data

I am using Facebook SDK for page status read, for this I am using the following  URL :

> https://graph.facebook.com/gennextapps/statuses?limit=50&access_token=" + access_token

At first I am getting values, but, after two times I am unable to get the values.

Is there any difference between statuses and feed in URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statuses and feed are two different things.  "Statuses" are only the items posted by the page, while "feed" includes items posted by others.

I found this [page documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

**Statuses**: An array of Status message objects. The Page's status updates.

**Feed**: An Array of Post objects containing (up to) the last 25 posts. The page's wall.

Comment: Check out the `stream` table.  You'd have to use FQL to get it.

Comment: You can filter out of the feed array all the statuses.  The post will have `type=status` as one of its attributes. Graph API example : `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?type=status`

Comment: @Lix  when i use this i am getting null..for pages , i am getting for user..  can post full link for getting both (feed as well as statuses ) if it's possible..

Comment: @Raja, did you check out the stream table?  There's lots of good data in there that can be gotten with one call.

Comment: are you the administrator of the page in question?